# Use tensorflow text_dataset_from_directory function instead of classfication but regression?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I use IMDB movie reviews dataset and put different reviews to different to different dir according to review rating.

like this:
[image]

and the code :

```
import os
import shutil
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow_text as text
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras import losses


AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE
batch_size = 32
seed = 42

raw_train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(
    'train',
    batch_size=batch_size,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset='training',
    label_mode='int',
    seed=seed)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(
    'train',
    batch_size=batch_size,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset='validation',
    label_mode='int',
    seed=seed)

test_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(
    'test',
    label_mode='int',
    batch_size=batch_size)

class_names = raw_train_ds.class_names

print(class_names)
```

output is like this:
[image]

but I want to predict unknown reviews rating via int value labels.

Answer (score 1):

ok, I append the int value to a list.

train_label =[]

when I use tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(),
I put the list of label on the param of labels.

```
raw_train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(
    'train',
    batch_size=batch_size,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset='training',
    labels = train_label,
    seed=seed
    )
```

when I print the label of dataset, it's seen work for now.

Comment: What is the batch size here? The number of text files your read each time? The number  of sentences? Or what?